# insert multi values from python list into sqlite table

Tags: python, database, list, sqlite

I have over ten thousand of data in python list and it take over 300 seconds to add data from list into
sqlite table.
I would like to know how to add multi data at the same time or the fastest method to do it.

`list_example  = [('ST0001', '2020-04-11', 23.0), ('ST0002', '2020-04-11', 20.0), ('ST0003', '2020-04-11', 75.0)]`

First code version:

```
import sqlite3

def add_temp_stock_data(PART_NO, INVDATE, COST):
    global conn
    global c
    conn = sqlite3.connect('PRODUCT_LIST.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT_LIST (
        PART_NO TEXT,
        INVDATE TEXT,
        COST REAL)
        """,
            )
    with conn:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO PRODUCT_LIST (PART_NO, INVDATE, COST)
                VALUES (?,?,?)""",
                  (PART_NO, INVDATE, COST,))
    conn.commit()

for i in range(len(list_example)):
    PART_NO = list_example[i][0]
    INVDATE = list_example[i][1]
    COST = list_example[i][2]
    add_temp_stock_data(PART_NO, INVDATE, COST)
```

Second code version:

```
def add_temp_stock_data(list_example):
    global conn
    global c
    conn = sqlite3.connect('PRODUCT_LIST.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT_LIST (
        PART_NO TEXT,
        INVDATE TEXT,
        COST REAL)
        """,
            )
    for i in range(len(list_example)):
        PART_NO = list_example[i][0]
        print(PART_NO)
        INVDATE = list_example[i][1]
        print(INVDATE)
        COST = list_example[i][2]
        print(COST)
        with conn:
            c.execute("""INSERT INTO PRODUCT_LIST (PART_NO, INVDATE, COST)
                    VALUES (?,?,?)""",
                      (PART_NO, INVDATE, COST,))
    print(list_example)
    conn.commit()
add_temp_stock_data(list_example)
```

Comment: Try putting many insert statements at a time in a single transaction. 
https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2

Comment: Only execute the `CREATE TABLE` query once, you'll need to move it out of `add_temp_stock_data()`. Don't create a new connection for each query. Just create a connection and pass it as an argument to `add_temp_stock_data()`, you'll need to handle the case in which the connection closes prematurely.

Comment: @Marichyasana I'm trying to do that thing,  but I'm a Python beginner So your useful link is too hard for me to understand.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Thank you, I did follow your recommendation, it's can reduce the time to be half!!. but I also do need to insert multi data in single transaction to make it faster if you don't mind please help.  :)

Comment: @wallefan's answer already uses a single transaction since `execute()` is actually implemented as `executemany()` under the hood. You can verify this by reading the source code or you can trust this Python-specific sqlite optimization [article](https://remusao.github.io/posts/few-tips-sqlite-perf.html). I'm running `executemany()` on data like yours with 100,000 inserts in under 100ms. You may be able to shave off a little more time by using `sqlite3.Connection.executemany` instead of `sqlite.Cursor.executemany`, but there's not much more room for improvement here in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [sqlite3.Cursor.executemany()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany).

```py
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```

Comment: it's fantastic! Thank you, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sqlite3

def add_temp_stock_data(PART_NO, INVDATE, COST):
    global conn
    global c
    conn = sqlite3.connect('PRODUCT_LIST.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT_LIST (
        PART_NO TEXT,
        INVDATE TEXT,
        COST REAL)
        """,
            )
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO PRODUCT_LIST(PART_NO, INVDATE, COST) VALUES (?,?,?)",(PART_NO,INVDATE,COST)
                )
    conn.commit()

for i in range(len(list_example)):
    PART_NO = list_example[i][0]
    INVDATE = list_example[i][1]
    COST = list_example[i][2]
    add_temp_stock_data(PART_NO, INVDATE, COST)
```

Comment: Sorry, it's error occurred as `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ST0001`